# Incompatible shape TensorFlow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting this error when I am trying to train my model:

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_encoder is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2048 but received input with shape [446, 98, 1024]`

My model architecture is:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(2048), name='Image_1')
dense1 = Dense(256, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed = 56), name='dense_encoder')(input1)

input2 = Input(shape=(153), name='Text_Input')
emb_layer = Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size, output_dim = 300, input_length=153, mask_zero=True, trainable=False, 
                weights=[embedding_matrix], name="Embedding_layer")
emb = emb_layer(input2)

LSTM1 = LSTM(units=256, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, 
            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=23),
            recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.orthogonal(seed=7),
            bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros(), return_sequences=True, name="LSTM1")(emb)
#LSTM1_output = LSTM1(emb)

LSTM2 = LSTM(units=256, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, 
            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=23),
            recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.orthogonal(seed=7),
            bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros(), name="LSTM2")
LSTM2_output = LSTM2(LSTM1)

dropout1 = Dropout(0.5, name='dropout1')(LSTM2_output)

dec =  tf.keras.layers.Add()([dense1, dropout1])

fc1 = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(seed = 63), name='fc1')
fc1_output = fc1(dec)
dropout2 = Dropout(0.4, name='dropout2')(fc1_output)
output_layer = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax', name='Output_layer')
output = output_layer(dropout2)

encoder_decoder = Model(inputs = [input1, input2], outputs = output)
encoder_decoder.summary()
```

Here's my code for training the model:

```
for epoch in range(20):
    print('EPOCH : ',epoch+1)
    start = time.time()
    batch_loss_tr = 0
    batch_loss_vl = 0
    
    for img, report in train_generator:
       
        r1 = bytes_to_string(report.numpy())
        img_input, rep_input, output_word = convert(img.numpy(), r1)
        rep_input = pad_sequences(rep_input, maxlen=153, padding='post')
        results = encoder_decoder.train_on_batch([img_input, rep_input], output_word)
        
        batch_loss_tr += results

    train_loss = batch_loss_tr/(X_train.shape[0]//14)
    with train_summary_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar('loss', train_loss, step = epoch)
    
    for img, report in cv_generator:
        r1 = bytes_to_string(report.numpy())
        img_input, rep_input, output_word = convert(img.numpy(), r1)
        rep_input = pad_sequences(rep_input, maxlen=153, padding='post')
        results = encoder_decoder.test_on_batch([img_input, rep_input], output_word)
        batch_loss_vl += results
```

The img_input shape is (417, 98, 1024) and I am getting the error for Image_1 layer.

What could be the reasons? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please mentioned inputs and its shape before fitting the model. This will help in understanding your problem better

Comment: Hey @ArunJoyThekkiniyath. I have edited my question. Can you please check it now?

Comment: You declared input shape of 2048 in the very first line. Try changing it to 1024

Comment: @Andrey I tried changing the value to 1024 but now I am getting another error which says ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 98 and 477 for '{{node functional_42/add_21/add}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT](functional_42/dense_encoder/BiasAdd, functional_42/dropout1/dropout/Mul_1)' with input shapes: [477,98,256], [477,256].

Comment: There is a second input (named as Text_input) to your model. It goes through a couple of LSTM layers. Looks like output shape of these layers is [477,256]. You are trying to add this output to the output of dense layer with shape [477,98,256]. These shapes are incompatible

Comment: Yes, got your point. Is there any way to achieve this thing?

Comment: Your model should be changed. The changes depend on the purpose and logic of your model